# How can we optimize gathering light through a finger from an LED?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses, optical-materials, light-emitting-diodes

We aren’t getting enough optical receive signal (ie. energy).
We have a finger ring with LEDs on either side of a photo detector, all on inside of ring.
Photo sensor has fixed field of view (FOV).
How can we get better/more light to detector from the transmit LED?